# Bluetooth starts up at login

Tags: bluetooth, 15.04

This has always annoyed me. Bluetooth turns on when I boot up my laptop, and it's a real drain if I forget to turn it off. It's been a year, and I'd like to find the solution, finally, here.

Thank you :)

Comment: If you are concerned about battery usage,I imagine you have check TLP in which settings you can set certain radio devices to turn off at startup.

Comment: A duplicate of a question asked years ago?

Answer (score 0):

Check `lsmod | grep btusb`
If it shows btusb then

```
echo "blacklist btusb" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/btusb.conf
```

Reboot and this should prevent bluetooth from working

And there is a udev rule that can be used if this doesn't work, just post the results of `lsusb`

Answer (score 0):

The bluez package installs /lib/udev/rules.d/50-bluetooth-hci-auto-poweron.rules. Removing it should avoid the auto poweron.